# Can I make a .vbs file to an .exe file?

Tags: exe, cmd

I am wondering a way to get something to make my .vbs file to an .exe file.

is it possible?

**Code:**

```
    Option Explicit

    Dim oShell : Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
    Dim FSO : set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
    Dim StartTime,Elapsed 

    'msgBox(oShell.CurrentDirectory)
    'MsgBox(FSO.GetFile(Wscript.ScriptFullName).ParentFolder )
    oShell.CurrentDirectory = FSO.GetFile(Wscript.ScriptFullName).ParentFolder

    StartTime = Timer

    IF NOT oShell.run( "ParentChildLinkFinal.vbs", 1, True) = 0 then Wscript.Quit
    IF NOT oShell.run( "Parent_Child_Merge_final.vbs", 1, True) = 0 then Wscript.Quit       

    Elapsed = Timer - StartTime

    MsgBox("Total time taken to finish this task:" & Elapsed & "in Seconds")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve it with this utility
http://www.vbs2exe.com/

Comment: I have one confusion,that If I make it .exe file,then will .vbs files included into the main.vbs file be able to act for which they are prepared? all the inside .vbs files are to work with Excel automation kind of tasks.